# Why one of my filter pipe is not showing up the results?

Tags: angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I have added another filter for DL. But my DL filter is not showing up the results. Can you please suggest what changes do I need to make?

```
<div class="form-group float-left mr-4">
<strong>DL</strong>
<br />
<select class="form-control form-control-sm" name="dl" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}">
<option></option>
<option value="CAT1">CAT1</option>
<option value="CAT2">CAT2</option>
</select>
</div>
```

table-filter.pipe.ts

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({
  name: "tableFilter"
})

export class TableFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(list: any[], filters: any) {
    const keys = Object.keys(filters).filter(key => filters[key]);
    const filterUser = (user: { [x: string]: any; }) =>
      keys.every(key => {
        if (key == "sdob") {
          return new Date(user["dob"]) >= new Date(new Date(filters[key]).setHours(0,0,0,0));
        } else if (key == "edob") {
              return new Date(new Date(filters[key]).setHours(0,0,0,0)) >= new Date(user["dob"]);
        } else {
          return user[key] === filters[key];
        }
      });
    return keys.length ? list.filter(filterUser) : list;
  }
}
```

URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dubf37?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

Add one more `else if` to your filter:

```
else if (
      key === "dl" &&
      user["assigned_to"].filter(e => e.dl === filters[key]).length
    ) {
      return user;
    }
```

https://angular-ivy-ehrh4h.stackblitz.io

Comment: did you make any other change as well expect this because when I am moving my code to local it's not working? :(

Comment: No, didn't do anything else, are you able to filter on stackblitz itself?

Comment: I can. Anyways can you please help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65679357/how-can-i-another-filter-for-score-which-will-show-the-results-matching-the-rang

Comment: is it something because my data is coming from api using httpclient  instead of service?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem, you can always debug.

Comment: If you have few more mins. can I request you please look into it? This is the last ask https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65678821/how-can-i-show-only-1-record-which-has-a-least-score-among-all